# Javascript recursion, memory leak?

Tags: node.js, recursion, memory-leaks, timer

I am trying to implement a class that will perform an action once every second, it works as expected but I am unsure about memory leaks. This code I'm writing will have an uptime of several months.

**Will the code below lead to memory leaks since it's technically recursion which never ends?**

```js
class Algorithm{
  constructor(){
    //there will be many more things in this constructor
    //which is why this is a class
    const pidTimer = (r,e=0,y=Date.now()-r) => {
      this.someFunction();
      const now = Date.now();
      const dy = now-y;
      const err = e+r-dy
      const u = err*0.2;
      //console.log(dy)
      setTimeout(()=>{pidTimer(r,err,now)},r+u);
    }
    pidTimer(1000);
  }

  someFunction = () => {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not the kind of recursion that has any stack accumulation since the previous `pidTimer()` function call returns before the `setTimeout()` fires and calls `pidTimer()` again.  I wouldn't even call this recursion (it's scheduled repeated calling), but that's more a semantic issue.

So, the only place I see there could be some memory leak or excess usage would be inside of `this.someFunction();` and that's only because you don't show us the code there to evaluate it and see what it does.  The code you show us for `pidTimer()` itself has no issues on its own.

Answer (score 2):

**modern async primitive**

There's nothing "wrong" with the current function you have, however I think it could be improved significantly. JavaScript offers a modernized asynchrony atom, [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and new syntax support [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). These are preferred over stone-age `setTimeout` and `setInterval` as you can easily thread data through asynchronous control flow, stop thinking in terms of "callbacks", and avoid side effects -

```js
class Algorithm {
  constructor() {
    ...
    this.runProcess(...)
  }
  async runProcess(...) { // async
    while (true) {        // loop instead of recursion
      await sleep(...)    // sleep some amount of time
      this.someFunction() // do work
      ...                 // adjust timer variables
    }
  }
}
```

`sleep` is a simple function which resolves a promise after a specified milliseconds value, `ms` -

```js
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms)) // promise
}
```

**async iterables**

But see how `this.someFunction()` doesn't return anything? It would be nice if we could capture the data from `someFunction` and make it available to our caller. By making `runProcess` an [async generator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for-await...of) and implementing [Symbol.asyncIterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/asyncIterator) we can easily handle asynchrony *and* stop side effects -

```js
class Algorithm {
  constructor() {
    ...
    this.data = this.runProcess(...)  // assign this.data
  }
  async *runProcess(...) {            // async generator
    while (true) {
      await sleep(...)    
      yield this.someFunction()       // yield
      ...
    }
  }
  [Symbol.asyncIterator]() {          // iterator
    return this.data
  }
}
```

Now the caller has control over what happens as the data comes in from `this.someFunction`. Below we write to `console.log` but you could easily swap this for an API call or write to file system -

```js
const foo = new Algorithm(...)
for await (const data of foo)
  console.log("process data", data) // or API call, or write to file system, etc
```

**additional control**

You can easily add control of the process to by using additional data members. Below we swap out `while(true)` with a conditional and allow the caller to stop the process -

```js
class Algorithm {
  constructor() {
    ...
  }
  async *runProcess(...) {
    this.running = true       // start
    while (this.running) {    // conditional loop
      ...
    }
  }
  haltProcess() {
    this.running = false      // stop
  }
  ...
}
```

**demo**

Here's a functioning demo including the concepts above. Note we only implement `halt` here because `run` is an *infinite* generator. Manual halting is not necessary for finite generators. Verify the results in your own browser by running the snippet -

```js
class Algorithm {
  async *run() {
    this.running = true
    while(this.running) {
      await sleep(1000)
      yield this.someFunction()
    }
  }
  halt() {
    this.running = false
  }
  someFunction() {
    return Math.random()
  }
  [Symbol.asyncIterator] = this.run
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}

async function main() {
  const foo = new Algorithm          // init
  setTimeout(_ => foo.halt(), 10000) // stop at some point, for demo
  for await (const x of foo)         // iterate
    console.log("data", x)           // log, api call, write fs, etc
  return "done"                      // return something when done
}

main().then(console.log, console.error) // "done"
```

```js
data 0.3953947360028206
data 0.18754462176783115
data 0.23690422070864803
data 0.11237466374294014
data 0.5123244720637253
data 0.39818889343799635
data 0.08627407687877853
data 0.3861902404922477
data 0.8358471443658225
data 0.2770336562516085
done
```